# select data from sqlite database and binding values to listbox item in windows phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am trying to creating windows phone 8 project with database (sqlite) techniques

I have tried the following:

1) Download sqlite fie from server & saved it in local app

2) I can also retrieve the values from local sqlite database and displayed in message box by using some sample codes from [This Link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone) & some other links too.

But, I am not able to bind that values in listbox.

Here is my code :

XAML code :

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListBox Name="scheduleListbox" Margin="5,85,5,60" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="scheduleListbox_SelectionChanged">
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="250" Width="480">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Name="team1Name" Text="{Binding team1_name}" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="team2Name" Text="{Binding team2_name}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="venue" Text="{Binding venue}" ></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <toolkit:ListPicker Name="selectTeam" Height="60" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" FullModeHeader="Select your Team Schedule" Foreground="White" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Margin="5,0" SelectionChanged="selectTeam_SelectionChanged">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="listpickerStackpannel" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="listpickerStackpannel" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
    </Grid>
```

and my CS code is:

```
     string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sample.sqlite");
    //SQLite connection
    private SQLiteConnection dbConn;
    private List<string> _source = new List<string>
    {
        "Full Schedule","Afghanistan","Australia","Bangladesh","England","Hong Kong","India","Ireland","Nepal","Netherlands","New Zealand","Pakistan","South Africa","Sri Lanka","UAE","West Indies","Zimbabwe"
    };
    public MainPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectTeam.ItemsSource = _source;
    }

    private void scheduleListbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
        /// Create the table Task, if it doesn't exist.
        dbConn.CreateTable<iccworldt20_schedule>();
        /// Retrieve the task list from the database.
        List<iccworldt20_schedule> retrievedTasks = dbConn.Query<iccworldt20_schedule>("select * from iccworldt20_schedule").ToList<iccworldt20_schedule>();
        /// Clear the list box that will show all the tasks.
        scheduleListbox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var t in retrievedTasks)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(t.ToString());
        }
    }
}
public class iccworldt20_schedule
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int match_id { get; set; }
    public string team1_Name { get; set; }
    public string team2_Name { get; set; }
    public string match_no { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string venue { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string day { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return team1_Name + ":" + team2_Name +venue;
    }
}
```

Please give some solution that how to retrieve values from sqlite DB and bind its values to listbox.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any code where you are adding data to a ListBox. If you have data pulled from the database, add it to ItemsSource property that's all.

```
scheduleListbox.ItemsSource = retrievedTasks;
```

I do not understand why you use ItemsSource="{Binding}" on selectTeam ListPicker when you fill it in the constructor. And why do you use the same to scheduleListbox. See [Binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If you youse empty binding syntax: {Binding}. The ListBox inherits the DataContext from a parent element. When the path is not specified, the default is to bind to the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

i got it., according to "Jan Smuda " reply i found solution for that .,

i removed the binding syntax (ItemsSource="{Binding}") in XAML code for both listpicker and listbox  and add itemsSource in code itself., like this

so my XAML code like this:

```
   <ListBox Name="scheduleListbox" Margin="5,85,5,60" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="100" Width="480" Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="CadetBlue">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding team1_Name}" Name="team1Name" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding team2_Name}" Name="team2Name" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding venue}" Name="venue" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <toolkit:ListPicker Name="selectTeam" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" FullModeHeader="Select your Team Schedule" Foreground="White" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Margin="5,0" SelectionChanged="selectTeam_SelectionChanged">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="listpickerStackpannel" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="listpickerStackpannel" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

and my CS code like this :

```
    string country = "Full Schedule";
    List<match_schedule> ScheduleList;
    // the local folder DB path
    string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sample.sqlite");
    //SQLite connection
    private SQLiteConnection dbConn;
    ProgressIndicator _progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    private List<string> _source = new List<string>
    {
        "Full Schedule","Afghanistan","Australia","Bangladesh","England","Hong Kong","India","Ireland","Nepal","Netherlands","New Zealand","Pakistan","South Africa","Sri Lanka","UAE","West Indies","Zimbabwe"
    };
    public Schedule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectTeam.ItemsSource = _source;
        Loaded += Schedule_Loaded;
    }

    void Schedule_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void selectTeam_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        country = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem.ToString();
        dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
        /// Create the table Task, if it doesn't exist.
        dbConn.CreateTable<match_schedule>();

        if (country == "Full Schedule")
        {
            ScheduleList = dbConn.Query<match_schedule>("select * from tableName").ToList<match_schedule>();
        }
        else
        {
           ScheduleList = dbConn.Query<match_schedule>("select * from tableName where team1_Name=? or team2_Name=?", country).ToList<match_schedule>();
        }
        scheduleListbox.ItemsSource = ScheduleList;         
    }
}
public class match_schedule
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int match_id { get; set; }
    public string team1_Name { get; set; }
    public string team2_Name { get; set; }
    public string match_no { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string venue { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string day { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I Got to retrieve column values from my local SQLite Database and i bind it in listbox.,

Lot of thanks to jan Smuda for responding me and thanks to stack overflow also.,